# Rendering Spring form:select Attributes

Tags: html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, rendering

In my JSP I'm trying to use JQuery Validate on my Spring form yet the validation never runs. The problem seems to be that the Spring form select element doesn't render attributes in the DOM. Below I have a small example to make the issue clearer with Spring form "foo" and the output in the DOM (note: I have the attribute modelAttribute on my Spring form and path on each Spring select that I have not included here). Is there a way to render the specified attributes?

```
<form:form id="foo">
    <form:select id="test" name="test" required>
        <form:option value="">Select Country</option>
        <form:option>US</option>
        <form:option>Canada</option>
    </form:select> <br />
</form:form>    
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick='$("#foo").valid()'> 

<script>
    $("#foo").validate();
</script>`
```

DOM:

```
<form id="foo">
  <select id="test">
     <option value="">Select Country</option>
     <option>US</option>
     <option>Canada</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Instead of looking at the server-side code, look at what  is ultimately rendered in the browser using your console tools.  What does `<form:form id="bar">` get turned into once it renders in the browser?  **JavaScript only cares about rendered code... and absolutely nothing about your framework.**

Comment: BTW, you should **not** need that inline `onclick` handler.  The plugin would already be capturing the click event here if you simply put the `submit` button **inside** the `<form></form>` container where it belongs.

Comment: Thanks that's actually intentional because of what I'm doing on my JSP (form is just being used to populate/fetch data with a button using those values). I just wanted to replicate in my example, sorry for confusion. I double checked the DOM and the problem seems to be with `<form:select required>`. It shows as `<select>` but it's unclear why required attribute is missing and why it's not validating

Comment: You also [**must** assign a `name` attribute to any field considered for validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-markup-recommendations).  It's how this plugin was designed to keep track of everything.  Without unique `name` attributes, validation is unpredictable or entirely broken.

Comment: I actually have a `name` attribute for each form element but after looking through the DOM, they're missing. Even though I specify `<form:select name="test" id="test" required>`, the DOM shows `<select id="test">`

Comment: At least you've narrowed it down to some HTML rendering problem within Spring or how you've implemented it.  Click the ["edit" button on your OP](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32654527/edit) to clarify this as the root problem you need to solve.  Once you get these attributes to render, the jQuery/JavaScript will work as designed.